# CloudFormation stack fails to deploy due to Resource of type 'AWS::Lambda::Function' with identifier '*' did not stabilize

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm deploying a CloudFromation stack via CDK, and it fails to deploy due to lambdas failing to stabilize.

Here is an example from the CloudFormation logs:

> Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::Lambda::Function' with identifier 'SearchEmailsFunction' did not stabilize." (RequestToken: 0056fd21-8850-6eeb-3dc5-abd64395af7d, HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized)

The strange this is the same stack has been deployed to several other account with no issue.

The stack consists of lambdas and a redis cache within a VPC. If we remove the redis cache and VPC, the stack deploys. However, when we update the stack to have the redis cache and VPC then random lambas fail to stabilize and the stack won't update.

What is the issue?